# Angular resource not returning proper JSON for PUT response

Tags: php, angularjs, json, rest, put

Using Angular `$Resource` for REST, `GET` is working fine but for `PUT` it is returning improper JSON format.

**Controller:**

```
myapp.controller('MovieEditController',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,Movie){
            $scope.updateMovie=function(){
                $scope.movie.$update(function(){
                    console.log($scope.movie);
                    $state.go('viewmovie');
                });
};
```

**Service:**

```
angular.module('app.services',[]).factory('Movie',function($resource){
return $resource('http://localhost/api/v1/api.php?id=:id',{id:'@uid'},{
update: {
method: 'PUT'
}
});
});
```

**Form:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" ng-model="movie.name" class="form-control" />

  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" ng-model="movie.desc" class="form-control"  />

  </div>

</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$txt);
```

But the data is not coming in proper format as `PUT` response, what to do so that data passes in proper format?

Comment: Does `file_get_contents("php://input")` contain anything?

Comment: Thanks @bstockwell: you can post as answer !

Comment: I had a feeling it was the `parse_str()`.